# React-navigation Redux State management

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm learning React Native and Redux and I've started using 3rd party libraries - specifically [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

I've followed a tutorial on it [Dan Parker's Medium Tutorial](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-navigation-with-complete-redux-state-management-tab-bar-and-multiple-navigators-ed30a69d9a4d) and I still can't get it working

My RootContainer of the app:

```
<PrimaryNavigation />
...

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(RootContainer)
```

PrimaryNavigation definition:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    navigationState: state.primaryNav
  }
}

class PrimaryNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PrimaryNav
        navigation={
          addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
            state: this.props.navigationState
          })
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrimaryNavigation)
```

PrimaryNav definition:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
  LoginScreen: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  MainContainer: {
    screen: MainContainer
  }
}

const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator(
  routeConfiguration,
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  })

export default PrimaryNav

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = PrimaryNav.router.getStateForAction(action,state)
  return newState || state;
}
```

My create store:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  primaryNav: require('../Navigation/AppNavigation').reducer
})

return configureStore(rootReducer, rootSaga)
```

I get an error along the lines of:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'PrimaryNavigation'`

My understanding so far is:

- RootContainer is connected to a store - it holds a PrimaryNavigation
- PrimaryNavigation contains a Navigator (PrimaryNav), it wraps the Navigator and passes it state
- PrimaryNav is the actual Navigator - I've defined routes and default initializations
- the reducer that handles PrimaryNav is just PrimaryNav.router.getStateForAction

Am I missing initial state? Am I not connecting it to Redux properly? Do I need to fire off a dispatch to go to the first screen?

Thanks

Comment: Are you require `PrimaryNav` properly? It's coming back as `undefined` so I'm guessing its a simple require failure of your component

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a few things in your code organization.

This is my effort to extend the github notetaker app done by Tyler Mcginnis. I updated the code to support latest versions of React and React Native, I also extended the app to use react-navigation supporting both iOS and Android. I added Redux to manage the store and used Redux-Sagas to handle asynchronous fetch of data.

https://github.com/ahmedkamohamed/react-native-navigation-redux-sagas

Answer (score 0):

you can see full demo from my git : https://github.com/liuxiaocong/redux-with-react-navigation
use redux and react-navigation from react-native

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers